# Narrow my selection to show only related records

Tags: netsuite

I have created to custom record types. Poll and Questions.

I would like to have a field in Poll to point to the starting question.
As such, I would like to user to click from a list of current poll questions.

However, I can't seem to find the right approach to filtering the set to just questions of the current poll.

What is the proper way to do this?

REVISED ADD ON QUESTION:

How do I narrow the selection on SCQP-Questin dropdown also?

[image: How do I narrow the selection on SCQP-Questin dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to do this in your field definition for the *Starting Question* field on the *Poll* record. Open up this field definition and take a look at the *Sourcing and Filtering* tab. There you should find a `FILTER USING` sublist; you can use this to set up the appropriate filtering.

The `FILTER USING` column will show you fields from the *Question* record. I assume that there is a field on the *Question* that links it to a *Poll*; this will be the field you select for `FILTER USING`. Next, select `equal to` for your `COMPARE TYPE`. Finally, in the `VALUE IS` column, select `CURRENT RECORD`. This should filter down the list of questions to only those that have the current Poll set.

Here's a screenshot of the table just to illustrate the columns I'm talking about. Obviously I don't have Poll and Question records set up so I can't show you exact fields set in the table.
[image: Filtering sublist]

Comment: CURRENT RECORD !! That was the secret. One last thing, how do I get the VIEW ... QUESTION area under my tab to not show all questions?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean or which tab you are talking about here. Can you clarify more?